# Make Volley GsonRequest with x-www-form-urlencoded header

Tags: http-headers, android-volley

I make a volley gsonrequest with x-www-form-urlencoded Content-Type header to asp.net API, but although with many ways it'still get 500 error code. This is my code:

```
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.append(NetworkAPI.BASE_URL).append(uri);

    GLog.i("net_post", stringBuilder.toString());
    GLog.i("net_params", new Gson().toJson(params));

    GsonRequest<T> gsonRequest = new GsonRequest<T>(Method.POST,
            stringBuilder.toString(), clazz, headers, params, listener) {

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
        }

    };
    gsonRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);

    requestQueue.add(gsonRequest);
```

I also tried to override getHeaders() method. It didn't work too.
Do you guys have any solution? Please advice.
Thank you.